# Trying to send value from javascript to python server

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have multiple input tags, my task is to collect the values entered by the user and send it back to the server. I am using Django as my framework. I am successful in sending the data to the client side (javascript). 
To return back the data from javascript function to my python function, I used XMLHttpRequest. 
I have added my code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>label{ text-align:center; width:250px; color:blue; display:inline-block}</style> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="'+url_read+'"></script>  
<script>
function submit_this()
{
var i,j;var arr=[];
for(i=0; i<Hello.length; i++)  
{
arr[i]=[];
for(j=0;j<Hello[i].length; j++) 
{
arr[i].push(document.getElementById(Hello[i][j]).value);
}
}
alert(document.getElementById(Hello[1][0]).value);  
xmlHttpReq =     new XMLHttpRequest();   
xmlHttpReq.open('POST', '/button_click',true);    
xmlHttpReq.send('w=' + encodeURI(arr));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<button id="submit_button" onclick="submit_this();" value="Submit">Submit</button>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code is stored in a string called html_string. 
Hello is a json object read from the file denoted by the varible url_read. It was dumped using Python. 
The plan was to use HttpResponse to send the html_string and render the html page in return.

I understand that I need to make one POST function in one of the classes in views.py. But unable to understand how to approach this problem.

I have to somehow send the javascript data structure named arr back to the server side. The main doubt is where can I put my code where I can read the value posted by the javascript function. 
I want to navigate to a new page once submit button has been pressed and in Django each url has a new function (in views.py) associated with it. Should I place it in that ?

Comment: please format your code.

Comment: typo in your js. change to `xmlHttpReq.open('POST', '/button_click',true);`

Comment: what is `Hello` in your code. is it declared somewhere else? just wondering if this is a keyword in js or etc...?

Comment: I forgot to point out, Hello is a json object which I passed through python. I converted the data structure into a json object and then dumped into the file which is represented by the varible url_read. The same file is read by javascript function as source to get the json object (Hello) .Hello contains the id's of the input elements and I use the javascript function getElementById to get the entered values by the user @Haranadh

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where in I am sending values to (Django)python server using JS, and receiving html rendered template.
I am using ul tag with id #Nearby to load html inside an html.
Ajax  success is returning html from django view rendered through url endpoint '/getGopoints/'

*template.html*

```
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <ul id="Nearby">

        </ul>
    </div>  
</div>

 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#dataTables-example1').DataTable({
                    responsive: true
            });
          getLocation();
    });
 function getLocation() {
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
        } 
    }


function showPosition(position) {
        $.ajax({
                url : '/getGopoints/', // the endpoint
                type : 'GET', // http method
                data : { 'lat' : position.coords.latitude,
                         'lon' : position.coords.longitude,
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
                 }, // data sent with the post request

                // handle a successful response
                success : function(data) {
                  $('#Nearby').html(data);  
                },
                dataType: 'html'

        });
    }
</script>
```

*urls.py*

```
 url(r'^getGopoints/$',views.getGopoints, name='getGopoints'),
```

*views.py*

```
def getGopoints(request):
    lat = str(request.GET['lat'])
    lon = str(request.GET['lon'])
    pnt=fromstr('POINT(%s %s)' %(lon,lat))
    with_in_distance = 20
    go_points = GoPoint.objects.filter(point__distance_lte=(pnt, D(km=with_in_distance)))
    context = RequestContext(request,
        {'go_points':go_points,
        'with_in_distance':with_in_distance,
        })
    return render_to_response('nearby.html',
                             context_instance=context)
```